# Fetching TMYs from the NSRDB for interval size in 5 minutes

Tags: pvlib

I am using pvlib https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/v0.9.0/generated/pvlib.iotools.get_psm3.html for retrieving NSRDB PSM3 time-series data from the PSM3 API. I was able to retrieve data for 30 minutes, but it doesn't work for changing the interval for 5 minutes!!! any help

```
 my_metadata, my_data = pvlib.iotools.get_psm3(
         latitude= xxx, longitude=xxx,
       interval=5,
       api_key=My_key, email='xxx',  # <-- any email works here fine
        #names='tmy'
         names='xxx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're using an older version of pvlib?  I would try updating to the latest version with `pip install -U pvlib` or similar.  You can check your installed version with `print(pvlib.__version__)`.

This snippet successfully retrieves 5-minute data for me with pvlib 0.9.1:

```py
import pvlib

lat, lon = 40, -80
key = '<redacted>'
email = '<redacted>'

df, metadata = pvlib.iotools.get_psm3(lat, lon, key, email, names='2020',
                                      interval=5, map_variables=True)
```

It's worth pointing out that TMYs are always hourly; the 5-minute data is only for single (calendar) years like the above `2020` request.  The `get_psm3` docstring mentions this:

```
interval : int, {60, 5, 15, 30}
    interval size in minutes, must be 5, 15, 30 or 60. Only used for
    single-year requests (i.e., it is ignored for tmy/tgy/tdy requests).
```

Comment: It works great after updating pvlib